# Asymptotic expansions: Dawson integral near 0 and infinity.

Tags: calculus

I was trying to find a series expression for $F(x)=e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt $ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$. Also I want to find the expansion using only the 'integration by parts' method.

First, I will show you my thought process when dealing with this kind of exercise:

Firstly, I do a iteration of integrating by parts (if it seems not to be a pretty expression, I try some change of variable or some other $u$ and $dv$), the obvious choice here is $u=e^{t^2}$ and $dv=dt$. This way, iterating and

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n 2^n}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}+R_N(x)$$

Where $R_N(x)$ is the remnant of order $N$ of the expansion.

At first glance this expression seems fine for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, though I find everywhere in the internet that another expression is given for this limit ($x\rightarrow \infty$). Rewriting the integral like:

$$\int_0^x \frac{1}{2t} \frac{d}{dt}(e^{t^2})dt$$

And integrating by parts now, choosing $u=1/2t$ and $dv=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t^2})$, we can get the expression (iterating N times):

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^{n+1} x^{2n+1}}+R_N(x)$$

Now, this last expansion is only valid for large $x$, because we need to make an approximation to cancel out some constant terms.

I can wrap my head around this, but my question now is, why is the second expression preferred over the first one in the case of $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Also, this method seems a bit arbitrary, it's usual for me to get questions about asymptotic expressions around infinity or zero, is there a standard way of dealing with those limits using only integration by parts?

Comment: Well, I'd assume that the second expression is preferred for $x\to\infty$ because it converges faster the greater $x$ is, whereas the first one converges more slowly the greater $x$ is.

Comment: For large $x$, I think that the formula is $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n+1} x^{2n+1}}+R_N(x)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oops, you are right about the $2^{n+1 }$ part, but the factorial I got it right. Even though, I'm not so concerned with this particular case and the precise calculation, I'm worried about the various methods there exist for finding these expressions and if there is a rule I could follow. But if there is no rule for calculating the expressions in the limits, so be it :/

Comment: The first one doesn't satisfy the definition of an [asymptotic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_series) for large $x$ (increasing powers of $x$ do not form an asymptotic scale). The remainder in $F(x) = x + R_0(x)$ is not asymptotically smaller than $x$ (which is to be expected, since $F(x) \sim 1/(2 x)$ when $x \to \infty$).

Comment: @Maxim Got it, now, is there any consistent rule for getting this expressions by parts?

Comment: For an arbitrary integrand, no. Suppose the integrand is $f(t) e^{x \phi(t)}$ and we want a large $x$ expansion. As a rule of thumb, IBP will work *if* the expansion is a power series in $1/x$ (that is, contains only integral powers of $x$).

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for clarifying, I think I got it. Try to derive negative powers of x if doing large x, and integrate positive powers of x y small x :)